# node.js cannot find a module in the same folder

Tags: node.js

Im trying to use a simple "colors" module to set cli-colors in my logs, nothing special.

Well, i have a module called `colors.js` in the path `./app/config/colors.js`, the content:

```
var clc = require('cli-color');

var colors = {
  ok: clc.cyan,
  error: clc.red.bold,
  warn: clc.yellowBright,
  high: clc.white.bgGreen
};

module.exports = colors;
```

Simple. Well, when i require it in the server.js (at the root of the project, above of /app) it works fine, but, when i try to use it in the `./app/config/db.js` it throws me an error:

```
Error: Cannot find module './app/config/colors.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/nano/Dev/bears-api/app/config/db.js:3:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
14 Sep 10:21:00 - [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Why if it works in the server.js?

Comment: you have to show us the require that fails

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You probably required the module using a relative path.

Relative paths are resolved in relation to the requiring module's location.

Quoting [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules)

> A module prefixed with './' is relative to the file calling require().
>   That is, circle.js must be in the same directory as foo.js for
>   require('./circle') to find it.

So if you did a

```
var whatever = require('./app/config/colors.js');
```

inside a module located in `./app/config/` then node will look for `./app/config/app/config/colors.js` and fail.

If both requiring and required module are in the same directory just use:

```
var whatever = require('./colors.js');
```

or even shorter:

```
var whatever = require('./colors');
```

Answer (score -8):

The module should be in the "node_modules" folder to access it like you have described.